# Click on p.class, hide div.class - Jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

Im creating an autogenerated page from an XML-structure, it has the style like;

```
<p class=foo>ClickMe</p>
<div class=foo">
 ###somedata####
</div>
```

and then another just like it, etc, etc.

The idea is that i then can click on the paragraf and show/hide the div content. (is this smart or can you do it in another more dynamic way?)

```
$("p").click(function()
    {
       $("div").toggle("fast");
    });
```

Now all "div" elements will hide, "div.nameonlcass" will do what i want, i have searched but have not manage to find how to get the class name.

Im new to jquery and im geussing this is a pretty easy fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which classname do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method of JQuery

```
$("p").click(function(){
     $(this).next("div").toggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is correct but using the tag directly inside the selector will apply your logic to all the available `<p>` and `<div>` on your HTML

so you can write it in the form below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.foo").click(function(){
       $(this).next("div.foo").toggle("fast");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you're looking for?

```
$('p.foo').click(function() {
   $(this).next('div.foo').toggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the problem is that i dont know the classname(since its generated from an xml), i just know that the "p" that is clicked has the same class that the "div" i want to hide.

Comment: If these are the only <p> on the site you could just remove the .foo.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you choose to add class to your html do it like this

```
<p class="foo">ClickMe</p>
<div class="foo"">
 ###somedata####
</div>
```

Second your jQuery code hides ALL div's because you select all div elements! Because `$('div')` selects all div elements on the HTML Page

You can either choose to hide all div's that have the class of "foo" which would be:

```
$('p').on("click",function(){
    $('div.foo').hide();// hides all the div's that have the class foo
});
```

But I would prefer to do it in an much more dynamic way:

```
$('p').on("click",function(){
   var classOfP=$(this).attr("class");
   var divSelector = "div."+classOfP;
   $(divSelector).hide();
});
```

So what this does it takes the class of the p Element you clicked and hides all div's which have the same class. With that you can structure your code much more.

And another thing that I would suggest is to use `.on("click",...)` because the event will be fired everytime and also if it gets added to the dome after creation. And `.on()` is the new "standard" for event handling since jQuery 1.7